# Defining new language grammar rules?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can you help me how could I edit the .tagger file using Stanford NLP? I have problem here, i can't open and edit the file to define the grammar rules for new language to generate part of speech?

Answer (score 0):

The `.tagger` files are serialized statistical models used by a Maximum Entropy based sequence tagger.  You can't edit them in any meaningful way.

If you want to create part of speech tags for a new language, you will have to create training data which consists of a large set of sentences in the language you want and having the correct part of speech tag for each word in the sentence, and then train a new part of speech tagging model.

Comment: There is very detailed documentation available here: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml